# Serialising with annotation groups

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, symfony-4.2

Symfony v4.2

I'm trying to use symfony's normalizer and serialiser to convert my entities into JSON.

I followed the Groups annotation pattern, because it sounds like the most intuitive and future proof way to do it.

According to [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#attributes-groups), we have to manually instantiate the `ClassMetadataFactory` in order to load the `AnnotationLoader`. I'm still using the `ObjectNormalizer` which worked fine before using annotations.

Here's my serialize method:

```
/**
 * @param bool $event Serialize all event fields (except references)
 * @param bool $meta Serialize referenced meta instance
 * @param bool $targets Serialize referenced target instances
 * @param bool $users Serialize referenced user instances
 * @param bool $videos Serialize referenced video instances
 * @param bool $photos Serialize referenced photo instances
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize($event = true, $meta = false, $targets = false, $users = false, $videos = false, $photos = false) {
    $serializingGroups = [];
    if ($event) {
        $serializingGroups[] = 'event';
    }
    if ($meta) {
        $serializingGroups[] = 'meta';
    }
    if ($targets) {
        $serializingGroups[] = "targets";
    }
    if ($users) {
        $serializingGroups[] = 'users';
    }
    if ($videos) {
        $serializingGroups[] = 'videos';
    }
    if ($photos) {
        $serializingGroups[] = 'photos';
    }

    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [new JsonEncoder()]);

    $data = $serializer->normalize($this, null, ['groups' => $serializingGroups]);
    return $serializer->serialize($data, 'json');
}
```

These groups are there to speed up serialization if I don't need associations te be serialized.

Now that I use group annotations, the json looks like this

```
"{"id":2,
"title":"test",
"description":"<p>&nbsp;test<\/p>",
"subscriptionPrice":"0.00",
"subscriptionUntil":[], // DATE  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"start":[], // DATE  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"end":[], // DATE  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"allDay":false,
"creationDate":[], // DATE  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"editDate":[], // DATE  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"editable":true,
"startEditable":true,
"durationEditable":true,
"overlap":false,
"color":"#9EABAB",
"backgroundColor":"#9eabab",
"borderColor":"#9eabab",
"textColor":"#000000",
"isRecurring":true,
"meta":[], // ASSOCIATED ENTITY  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
"targets":[[]] // ASSOCIATED COLLECTION OF ENTITIES  - WHY EMPTY ARRAY?
}"
```

Why does it work when I don't use annotations?
Why are dates and other entities empty arrays when I do use annotations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureca!

Here is a code snippet from my serialize method:

```
$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
$serializer = new Serializer([
    // Add a Datetimenormalizer as the first normalizer in the list
    new DatetimeNormalizer(),
    $normalizer
], [new JsonEncoder()]);

return $serializer->serialize($this, 'json', [
    // $serializer->addCircularReferenceHandler() IS DEPRECATED
    // define the handler like this:
    ObjectNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($event) {
        return '/event/'.$event->id;
    }
    ,ObjectNormalizer::GROUPS => $serializingGroups
]);
```

First of all, the reason why `meta` and `targets` weren't serializing was because I had the wrong import in my `Meta` and `Target` entities. Make sure it is: `use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;`... so... yeah... moving on.

The dates did serialize when I commented out `//,ObjectNormalizer::GROUPS => $serializingGroups`. So why don't they serialize when groups aren't commented out?
My guess is that the `DateTime` class doesn't have the `Groups` annotations, so the normalizer was never able to get any of the `DateTime` attributes

This is solved by adding a `DatetimeNormalizer` as the first normalizer in the array: `$serializer = new Serializer([new DatetimeNormalizer(),$normalizer])`

This is how my entities serialize correctly :D